# Cómo cambiar camara frontal a trasera y viceversa mediante un boton?

Tags: android, android-studio, cámara

Estoy usando OpenCV en Android, necesito acceder a ambas camaras y mediante un boton requiero cambiar de cámara a visualizar, similar a la aplicación de Cámara que viene en los dispositivos.

Answer (score -2):

[esta fue la respuesta correcta de mjosh en SO en inglés para esta consulta:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17117023/4959545)

```
Button otherCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OtherCamera);

OtherCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if (inPreview) {
    camera.stopPreview();
}
//NB: if you don't release the current camera before switching, you app will crash
camera.release();

//swap the id of the camera to be used
if(currentCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){
    currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
}
else {
    currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
}
camera = Camera.open(currentCameraId);

setCameraDisplayOrientation(CameraActivity.this, currentCameraId, camera);
try {

    camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
camera.startPreview();
}
```

Si desea hacer que la imagen de la cámara gire en la misma orientación que la pantalla, puede utilizar el siguiente código.

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
         int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
             new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
             .getRotation();
     int degrees = 0;
     switch (rotation) {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
     }

     int result;
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
         result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
     } else {  // back-facing
         result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
     }
     camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
 }
```